# Python : switching values in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to switch correct to false and false to correct in my panda data frame, doing what I have written below changes everything to correct. How do I fix this?

a.loc[(a["outcome"] == 'correct') 'outcome'] = 'false' and                                                                                                      a.loc[(a["outcome"] == 'false'), 'outcome'] = 'correct'

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary and if some another values out of `dict` add `fillna`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'outcome':['correct','correct','false', 'val']})
print (a)
   outcome
0  correct
1  correct
2    false
3      val

d = {'correct':'false', 'false':'correct'}
a['outcome'] = a['outcome'].map(d).fillna(a['outcome'])
print (a)
   outcome
0    false
1    false
2  correct
3      val
```